# While running react component test in a react-redux app, "Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__compose__.a.apply(...) is not a function"

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, web-applications, react-redux, enzyme

I have a react-redux application, in which i am trying to run test cases for a react component something like below:

```
class Login extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.checkUserAuth();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEnvConfig();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticating && this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      hashHistory.push('/dashboard');
  }
}

getAbc() {
  return this.props.abc;
}

anotherLogin() {
  return () => {
    const anotherURL = `${this.props.envConfig.AuthUrl}?response_type=code&client_id=${this.props.envConfig.ClientId}&redirect_uri=${this.props.envConfig.CallbackUri}&state=8.0`;
    /* global window */
    window.location.assign(anotherURL);
  };
}

  myLogin() {
    return () => {
      const loginUrl = `${this.props.envConfig.AuthUrl}?

     scope=urlScope&client_id=${this.props.envConfig.ClientId}&redirect_uri
        =${this.props.envConfig.RedirectUri}&response_type=token`;
     /* global window */
     window.location.assign(loginUrl);
   };
 }

 render() {
   if (this.props.isAuthenticating && !this.props.isAuthenticated) {
     return (<div>loading</div>); // needs to implement and include loading 
     component
   } else if (!this.props.isAuthenticating && !this.props.isAuthenticated) {
     return (
      <Grid fluid="true">
      <Row>
        <Col md={6} bsClass="xyz">
          <div className="left-login-container">
            <LoginLeft
              logo={logo}
              box={box}
              abc={this.abc()}
            />
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col md={6} bsClass="xyz">
          <div className="right-login-container">
            <LoginRight
              myLogin={this.myLogin()}
              anotherLogin={this.anotherLogin()}
            />
           </div>
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </Grid>
    );
   }
   return null;
  }
 }

  Login.defaultProps = {
    abc: '0',
    getEnvConfig: () => {},
    envConfig: {
    sfdcAuthUrl: '',
    sfdcCallbackUri: '',
    sfdcClientId: '',
  },
  isAuthenticating: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  checkUserAuth: () => {},
 };

 Login.propTypes = {
    abc: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    getEnvConfig: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    envConfig: PropTypes.shape({
       AuthUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       CallbackUri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       ClientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
    isAuthenticating: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    checkUserAuth: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     return {
       myLogin: (data) => {
         dispatch(myLogin(data));
       },
       getEnvConfig: () => {
         dispatch(getEnvConfig());
       },
       checkUserAuth: () => {
         dispatch(getUserInfo());
       },
     };
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
        return {
          abc: state.Login.Summary.Report,
          envConfig: state.EnvConfig.envConfig,
          isAuthenticating: state.Auth.isAuthenticating,
          isAuthenticated: state.Auth.isAuthenticated,
        };
     }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

I am going somewhere wrong in mocking the store and creating the shallow for his login component before even writing a test case i am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__compose**.a.apply(...) is not a function" Not sure abt the reason behind it. Here is the spec file content:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import LoginReducer from '../../../reducers/rootReducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import Login from './LoginPage';

const mockStore = configureStore([LoginReducer]);
const initialState = {
  SummaryStats: {
    Reports: '0',
  },
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isAuthenticating: true,
  userInfo: {
    firstName: 'Ruchir',
  },
  envConfig: {},
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);
const dummyData = {
  abc: '0',
  getEnvConfig: () => {},
  envConfig: {
    AuthUrl: '',
    CallbackUri: '',
    ClientId: '',
  },
};

const LoginWrapper = shallow(<Login 
    store={store}
    {...dummyData}
  />);

describe('<Login />', () => {    
  it('check componentDidMount method', () => {
    LoginWrapper.componentDidMount();
    expect(LoginWrapper.props().getEnvConfig).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Are your `import ... from '../../../reducers/rootReducers';` lines valid? I expect it to be just one line like `import rootReducer, {LoginReducer} from '../../../reducers/rootReducers';` instead of two.

Comment: Anthony, that wasn't the concern may be while trying out few changes i did that by mistake, for the time being i have just put the LoginReducer there. I am really not sure what is the reason behind the webpack module error.

Comment: If so, you should correct your code in the question.  You are expected to provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated that